# Finding Android File Paths

Tags: android, file

I am making a comic book reading app. I took my comics and created a folder on my phone for them. I am trying to test my file reader but, I have no idea how to find the path to the folder on my phone programmatically. I don't want to hard code the path. I have been searching all day and can't find a way to do this. Maybe i'm not understanding something right. Feel free to ask me more questions about what I'm trying to do. I'm so frustrated that i'm probably not explaining it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I'm running android 6. in which the permissions are done differently. Once I went into the settings and enable my apps storage permission. this chunk of code worked.

```
File yourFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"your_folder_name");
if(!yourFolder.exists()) {
    yourFolder.mkdir();
}
```

Thanks @ELITE

Answer (score 0):

There are some methods can help in `Context` class:

> getFilesDir() returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.
>
> openFileOutput (String name, int mode) Open a private file associated with this Context's application package for writing. Creates the file if it doesn't already exist.

more methods can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int))

Comment: I've seen that one. but is the string in openFileOutput, is that a file or a folder. I mainly need the folder path. Because i have my own class that handles the files inside.

Comment: @I know,but  `getFileDir` can get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
File yourFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "your_folder_name");
if(!yourFolder.exists()) {
    yourFolder.mkdir();
}
```

it'll create a folder on enternal storage and you dont have to hardcode the file path..

Comment: is there a fuction i can use to list all the files in that directory?

Comment: yep, you can use `yourFolder.listFiles()` method which returns `File[]` or you can do the same for parent folder `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles()`

Comment: that might be just what i needed

Comment: External storage doesn't appear to be the right path i have no sd card because i have a nexus 5x

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` what is returns on Nexus 5x??

Comment: That I will have to find out. I think it returns /system but I'm not sure.

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Comics that is the path. however my comics folder is in /root/sdcard/. which is weird because my phone has no sd card.